# Quick question about subspaces, bases and linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be an $n-$dimensional vector space and $Z$ be an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $X$. If $\{e_1, ..., e_{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $Z$, is it true that I can always find a vector $e_n \in X$ linearly independent to this basis?

This is something that I would expect to be true but I would appreciate any help justifying this assertion.

Comment: In retrospect this was a bit of a silly question. But it's always good to question everything! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any vector in $X$ but not in $Z$ works.

Indeed, let $v \in X \setminus Z$. Suppose we have
$$
\alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2 + \cdots + \alpha_{n-1} e_{n-1} + \beta v = 0  
$$

If $\beta=0$, then $\alpha_i=0$ for all $i$ because $e_1, \dots, e_{n-1}$ are linearly independent.

If $\beta\ne0$, then $v=\alpha_1' e_1 + \alpha_2' e_2 + \cdots + \alpha_{n-1}' e_{n-1} \in Z$, where $\alpha_i'=\alpha_i/\beta$. But this contradicts $v \notin Z$.

Thus, $e_1, \dots, e_{n-1}, v$ are linearly independent (and so a basis for $X$, because $X$ has dimension $n$).

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this is to take some basis $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ of $X$. If all elements of $f_i$ are in $Z$ then they are not linearly independent, so some $f_i$ is not in $Z$, and can be added to the basis. This observation leads to the definition of a [matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Let $\{f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_n\}$ be a basis for $X$.  Project each element $f_i$ onto $\{e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}\}$.  Either (1) the projection of $f_i$ will be $f_i$ itself, or (2) there will be a component of $f_i$ for some $i$ that is not a linear combination of the elements of the basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}\}$.  This vector is $e_n$.

How do we know that such a vector exists?  Well what if we could express every $f_i$ as a linear combination of the elements of $\{e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}\}$.  Since every element of $X$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\{f\}$, by transition, every element of $X$ would be a linear combination of $\{e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}\}$.  But this would mean that $\{e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $X$, which would mean that the dimension of $X$ is $n-1$, which is a contradiction.